# Recover Text within iPhone Notes (seeking advice other than "shaking" the phone)

Tags: iphone, notes.app, data-recovery

In my iPhone notes, I had created a "note" and had lots of text typed in there. By mistake, I deleted most of the text I had typed inside of the "note". Is there a way I can retrieve that text? I did not delete the whole note, only text inside the note was deleted, so what I want to know is if I can recover that text or not.
I have attempted to use the undo function by shaking the phone. Unfortunately, this feature will not recover the text. Any and all advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Undo has a single step. If you did something else in the meantime, it's gone, unless you had it saved or backed up somewhere else.

Comment: I don't know of retrieval, but if you can add shake to undo to screen accommodation, it will be safer in future.